# Image is not fitting properly

Tags: android, android-layout

I need mine to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOXVf.png), this is the iPhone version. Currently my android looks like this [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLjEI.png). Here's the XML layout code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativelayout02"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/model"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="300"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/brandname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:paddingTop="6dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_chrysler" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativelayout04"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/relativelayout02"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_header"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" >

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/RadioGroup1"
                android:layout_width="68dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/option1"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:button="@drawable/custom_radio"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:visibility="invisible" >
                </RadioButton>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/option2"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:button="@drawable/custom_radio"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:visibility="invisible" >
                </RadioButton>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/option3"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:button="@drawable/custom_radio"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:visibility="invisible" >
                </RadioButton>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/option4"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:button="@drawable/custom_radio"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:visibility="invisible" >
                </RadioButton>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/option5"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:button="@drawable/custom_radio"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:visibility="invisible" >
                </RadioButton>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/option6"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:button="@drawable/custom_radio"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:visibility="invisible" >
                </RadioButton>
            </RadioGroup>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativelayout03"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/relativelayout04"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/vehicleimg"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativelayout03"
                android:src="@drawable/chrysler_twohundred" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/vhc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_vhc"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/subhead"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:src="@drawable/shape_subhead" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout05"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/relativelayout03" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/line1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/border" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/status"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/line2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/status"
                android:background="@drawable/border" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout05"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:focusable="true"      
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/unlock"
                style="@style/chryslerButtonStyle"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_unlock" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/lock"
                style="@style/chryslerButtonStyle"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_lock" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout02"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout01"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/remotestart"
                style="@style/chryslerButtonStyle"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_ignitionstart" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/remoteturnoff"
                style="@style/chryslerButtonStyle"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_ignitionstop" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout03"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout02"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/remotehornsandlights"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:background="@drawable/chrysler_btn_bkg"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_lightsandhorn" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/vehiclehealthcheck"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:background="@drawable/chrysler_btn_bkg"
                android:text="Vehicle Information"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Tweddle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:background="@drawable/chrysler_btn_bkg"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/tweddle_status"
                android:paddingLeft="82dp"
                android:paddingRight="60dp"
                android:text="Via Mobile"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout04"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout03"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/contactus"
                style="@style/chryslerButtonStyle"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_contactus" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/help"
                style="@style/chryslerButtonStyle"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_help" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ext1"
                style="@style/chryslerButtonStyle"
                android:background="@drawable/chrysler_btn_bkg"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ext2"
                style="@style/chryslerButtonStyle"
                android:background="@drawable/chrysler_btn_bkg"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

When I double click the image from the graphical view layout, the following code is highlighted.

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/vehicleimg"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativelayout03"
                android:src="@drawable/chrysler_twohundred" />
```

What I tried is I changed the layout_width and height to wrap content or fill_parent, tried various combinations of it. Also tried this in the @+id/relativelayout03. Anybody has an idea on this?
The problem is with the center images. It should be stretched out and should like the the first one, no borders, it should just blend in.
Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Without knowing what I'm looking for, it's hard to see what the problem is.

Comment: I think you should share your images,  should put layout and drawable folder to dropbox and share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you try to set android:scaleType in the ImageView?
something like:

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/vehicleimg"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativelayout03"
                android:src="@drawable/chrysler_twohundred" 
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Please see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType for available options.